# Emacs Lisp: #s does not create a new hash table each time

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following function:

```
(defun inc-map ()
  (let ((ht #s(hash-table test contents-hash))) 
    (dolist (i (list 1 2 3 4))
      (let ((old-val (or (gethash "foo" ht)
             0)))
    (puthash "foo" (+ 1 old-val) ht)))
    ht))
```

Despite the fact that this function seems to define the `ht` symbol locally, the function doesn't seem to be referentially transparent.  In particular, calling it once returns the hash table `"foo" -> 4`, calling it a second time returns `"foo" -> 8`, a third time returns `"foo" -> 12` and so on.

What exactly is going on here and how do I change this function to be referentially transparent (and return `"foo" -> 4` every time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be considered a (slight) documentation bug, in that it suggests a little too firmly that using the printed representation creates a *new* hash table -- a statement which is open to misinterpretation.

However, you'll note that the documentation says that it's the elisp *reader* that recognises the printed representation of a hash table.

Therefore using `#s` is not the same as calling `make-hash-table`. The difference here is equivalent to the difference between quoting a list `'(1 2 3)` and calling `(list 1 2 3)`.

The former in each case is processed by the *reader* and hence the same, single resulting object (hash table or list respectively) is seen during each evaluation.

Conversely, in the latter instances the reader is generating code which, when evaluated, will create a new hash table or list; and therefore you see a new object during each evaluation.

Comment: Is it possible to modify `'(1 2 3)` so it actually return list with not/not only `1 2 3`?

Comment: user1034749: I'm not sure I understand the question. `'X` for any X is shorthand for `(quote X)`. X can be any form understood by the elisp reader, and it will evaluate to the object created by the reader. See `C-h f quote`

Comment: you make analogy between `#s` and `'(1 2 3)`, in question `#s(something)` and `#s(something)` can give different result, so is it possible to recieve different results evaluating  `'(1 2 3)` several times? like `'(1 2 3)` first time, and `'(1 2 3 4)` in the next time?

Comment: If it's the *same object*, then yes, absolutely. The lisp *reader* reads `'(1 2 3)` and creates a list object containing those three members. During evaluation, other code could then manipulate that list object in any way. The fact that the code which was *originally* read was `'(1 2 3)` does not mean that the structure of the associated lisp object must *continue* to represent that original textual form. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20535/why-the-constant-in-let-designed-in-this-way is a good example.

Comment: So is it possible to write `inc-list` without global variables usage, with similar structure, which return `(1 2 3) on first call and `(2 3 4) on the second?

Comment: Yes. See the Q&A link I added to my previous comment for an example of something similar. Take some time to research and understand the difference between the read and eval stages of lisp. Doing so will really de-mystify this kind of behaviour, and enable you to avoid inadvertently writing self-modifying code!

Comment: Thanks for answer, looks like `elisp` is more complex then `c++`.

Comment: Presumably, by doc, you mean the Elisp manual, node [Creating Hash](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Hash.html). There it says "You can also create a new hash table using" `#s`, which I agree is misleading. I just filed [bug #23417](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23417) for this.

Comment: @user1034749: Lisp is both simpler and more complex than C++. In general, it is much simpler (IMO). But if you are used to C or C++ then some things about it can appear complex.