# Why is this global variable only able to be set twice, and no more?

Tags: lisp, elisp, emacs24

I was trying to make a simple parser in elisp, and I encountered a problem where I `defvar` a global, then later I `setq` a new value into it.  This works the first time.  However, later `setq`'s fail every time.

The following code is a simplication of the problem:

```
(defvar buf '(BUF))
(defvar head nil)

(defun pparse (seq)

  (defun status ()
    (princ (format "Parse: %40s || %-20s\n"
           (prin1-to-string seq) (prin1-to-string buf))))

  (while seq
    (status)
    (setq head (car seq))
    (setq seq (cdr seq))
    (cond ((equal "x" head)
       (nconc buf (list head)))
      ((equal "," head)
       (setq buf '(BUF))
       ;;(setcdr buf nil) <- fixes it but doesn't answer my question
      )))

  (status))

(pparse '("x" "," "x" "," "x" "," "x"))
```

Which produces this output:

```
Parse:            ("x" "," "x" "," "x" "," "x") || (BUF)               
Parse:                ("," "x" "," "x" "," "x") || (BUF "x")           
Parse:                    ("x" "," "x" "," "x") || (BUF)               
Parse:                        ("," "x" "," "x") || (BUF "x")           
Parse:                            ("x" "," "x") || (BUF "x")           
Parse:                                ("," "x") || (BUF "x" "x")       
Parse:                                    ("x") || (BUF "x" "x")       
Parse:                                      nil || (BUF "x" "x" "x")
```

As you can see, the second column was clipped once, but grew every subsequent time.

If you uncomment the `setcdr` line, this works as expected (output is as follows).  You can even dump the `setq`.  I understand why this fixes it, but not why the original error happens in the first place.

```
Parse:            ("x" "," "x" "," "x" "," "x") || (BUF)               
Parse:                ("," "x" "," "x" "," "x") || (BUF "x")           
Parse:                    ("x" "," "x" "," "x") || (BUF)               
Parse:                        ("," "x" "," "x") || (BUF "x")           
Parse:                            ("x" "," "x") || (BUF)               
Parse:                                ("," "x") || (BUF "x")           
Parse:                                    ("x") || (BUF)               
Parse:                                      nil || (BUF "x")
```

BTW, the behavior is the same even if i turn off lexical scoping.

Comment: Note that `defun` does define GLOBAL functions, not local functions. For local functions one can use `cl-flet` or `cl-labels`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected persistence of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790192/unexpected-persistence-of-data)

Comment: And other related Q&As: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20535 http://stackoverflow.com/q/36964728

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot mutate literal data, such as `'(BUF)`, and expect sane results. And in your code, the `nconc` is a mutating operation.

In terms of the "why" you're seeing the behaviour you're seeing, it's due to the `(setq buf '(BUF))` expression. That sets it to the *same* object each time, because it's a literal datum—which you're not supposed to mutate with the likes of `nconc`. If you changed it to `(setq buf (list 'BUF))`, then it would generate a new object each time, and you can safely `nconc` *that*.

Comment: Would it also work to use a backquote to construct the list, since it's whole purpose in life is to construct new lists?

Comment: @JoelMWard From some brief testing, Emacs seems to follow the same rules as Scheme in this regard, so I'll quote you what R7RS says about it: _A quasiquote expression may return either newly allocated, mutable objects or literal structure for any structure that is constructed at run time during the evaluation of the expression. **Portions that do not need to be rebuilt are always literal.**_ (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: @JoelMWard In other words, unless you know how quasiquote expressions are built, it's best to assume it's immutable too. But if you know what you're doing, you can get away with it. :-) In the case of your code above, `\`(,'BUF)` works (from my testing), but not `\`(BUF)`.

Comment: It seems like this could be considered sort-of-like-static variables in C.  You get one shot to initialize then they're the same from then on.  Of course, as we've seen, this is implementation dependent and also probably extremely hard to keep track of as a programmer.

This sort of bug could probably be minimized if the literal data was also constant, as in C.  At least the error message would point you in the right direction.

Comment: Making all quoted data constant would break all manner of things; so you'd need a different syntax for defining constant data, at which point you need to remember to *use* that syntax, at which point you're back where you started -- needing to know when you can and can't quote data the normal way.

Comment: Rather than point the finger at the `'(BUF)`, I'd point the finger at `nconc`.  Just always use `append` unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way data identity works in Elisp.  If you replace `nconc` with `append` you'll be isolated from those problems.  I strongly recommend you stay away from `nconc` (and friends like `setcdr`) in general, and especially as long as you're not really familiar with Elisp.